# H2 query performance slow for Where In

Tags: database, performance, h2

Using the H2 1.2.147.jar I found that performance slowed down dramatically as soon as a Where In clause used an OR (which was needed once 255 specific items were listed).  For example

```
... WHERE
   (ID IN (?, ?, ...) OR (?, ?, ...)
```

Query performance was 1 or 2 orders of magnitude faster per item when an OR was not included which was seen when running smaller queries.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the page size to 255 (limiting queries to retrieve only 255 items for 255 IDs per query) resolved the performance issue and greatly improved performance.